# How to update BuddyPress xprofile fields programmatically?

Tags: functions, database, users, buddypress, table

I update user info using `wp_update_user` function. I also need to update the table `wp_bp_xprofile_data`. Is there any function, where I can update data on `wp_bp_xprofile_data` table?

Comment: Stupid that buddy press questions are closed as off topic. Google brought me here, and it provided the answer I needed. This is exactly what Stack Exchange sites are for, and if questions about one of the most popular WordPress plugins can't be asked in WordPress Dev, where is it supposed to be asked?

Comment: I had not noticed that they closed this thread as off-topic. Strange! But fortunately by that time the answer has been already answered.

Comment: All third party plugins are off-topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how I would update a field named 'Address':

```
function updateAddress() {

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $newAddress = '123 New Street';

    xprofile_set_field_data('Address', $current_user->id,  $newAddress);

}
```